# How can i invoke my own javascript API on my SWF dynamically embeded using swfOject?

Tags: javascript, flash, dynamic, swfobject, externalinterface

I am using the [`swfObject library`](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to dynamically embed a MP3 player i've made in Flash CS5. In the `.fla` file, i've declared a list of methods that can be called via Javascript (using the [`flash.external.ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) flash class).

That's not the problem since all these function work properly when called from Google Chrome's console.
However, swfObject provides a way to invoke javascript API only if the `.swf` has been **statically** included (i.e. using `swfobject.registerObject()` ) but i can't find a way to achieve the same goal when the `.swf` is **dynamically** included (i.e. using `swfobject.embedSWF()` ).

Thanks in advance for your help and contibutions :)

Comment: doesn't a good document.getElementById do the trick?

Comment: i tried it but it only works from the console, not when the `document.getElementById()` code is inside my <script> tags

Comment: You have to write the script tag after the element you want to get in your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `swfobject.embedSWF`, you can specify the ID of the swf object in the `attributes` parameters :

> swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, id, width, height, version, expressInstallSwfurl, flashvars, params, **attributes**, callbackFn)

Example :

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
    "YourFlash.swf", "WhereToPlaceThis", "0px", "0px", "10.0.0",
    "expressInstall.swf", {}, {}, { id : "IdOfTheSWF" },
    function () {
         var SWF = document.getElementById("IdOfTheSWF"); // That's your SWF //
         SWF.yourFlashFunction(); // And you can invoke function //
    }
);
```